# Finding things like termination date and employment status in the Workday API?

Tags: workday-api

I am looking to grab the following from Employee Population & Terminations part of Workday using the REST API:

Termination date, Last Updated, Status, Employment Status

Access Level to Workday, Revoked Date, Revoked By

Does anyone know where in the Workday REST API these can be found?

https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/restapi/index.html#common/v1/workers

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [SOAP API](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/operations/index.html) to get at this info. If you have to use REST, you will need to look into WQL and then directly query a data source.